# What is the correct term to describe "An animal with the ability to fly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

After searching I couldn't find anything, with the closest depiction being a pilot.

"___ animals have a different form of locomotion to aquatic or terrestrial animals."

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence where you'd use the word?

Comment: "_ animals have a different form of locomotion to aquatic or terrestrial animals."

Comment: "Flying" seems an obvious solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Volant**

> (of an animal) able to fly or glide. [Google Dictionary]
>
> A number of animals have evolved aerial locomotion, either by powered
>   flight or by gliding. Flying and gliding animals (volant animals) have
>   evolved separately many times, without any single ancestor. Flight has
>   evolved at least four times, in the insects, pterosaurs, birds, and
>   bats.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_and_gliding_animals ]

Comment: Can you give a source for your definition? You should also fix the formatting. Answers that don't give proper attribution may be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I would say they are **flying animals**.

Flying birds are by far the most common, but we also have flying mammals. We once had flying reptiles but these became extinct long ago. Flying fish are a family of marine fish that can fly short distances horizontally (see [**"gliding flight"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliding_flight))

> [**"flying"**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/flying) - adj -  moving or capable of moving in the air

Comment: This.  'volant' might be the correct technical term, but, unlike it, in mosts contexts 'flying' will be clear and immediately recognizable.